# Why FTPConnectionClosedException is thrown for a folder with 170K files over FTP?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am trying to rename the files over FTP using commons net FTP 3.5 and Java  1.8.0.45. There is one specific folder with 170K small files (25 GB) in it. Whenever I try to list this folder, it returns below exception. For rest of folders, it runs fine and renaming the files.

```
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:316)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:712)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1857)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3420)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3335)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:3012)
    at TestFTP.execute(TestFTP.java:27)
    at TestFTP.main(TestFTP.java:12)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:316)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:628)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:602)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:884)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:1152)
    at TestFTP.execute(TestFTP.java:62)
    at TestFTP.main(TestFTP.java:12)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class TestFTP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFTP.execute(args[0], args[1]);
    }
    static DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    public static void execute(String ip, String folder) {
        String server = ip;
        int port = 21;
        String user = "adminuser";
        String pass = "adminuser";

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);

            FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(folder);
            for (FTPFile file : files) {
                String details = file.getName();

                // renaming file
                String oldFile = folder + file.getName();
                String newFile = folder + "_X_" + file.getName();

                boolean success = ftpClient.rename(oldFile, newFile);
                if (success) {
                    System.out.println(oldFile + " was successfully renamed to: "
                            + newFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to rename: " + oldFile);
                }
            }

            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("time:"  +(end-start));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make my FTP server to respond request to list such a large folder like increasing timeout ? or Do I miss something ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have and Idea how much time is taking to do the list of the files?

Comment: Hold the phone. Why on earth are you using FTP to rename 170,000 files? It will be orders of magnitude more efficient to do this directly at the server. And I would use a batch file or a shell script, not Java code.

Comment: @DanielHernández Listing was never successful for this folder. For other folders which has around 100 files it took around 500 milliseconds.

Comment: @EJP Thats a valid statement, but I have lot of "other stuff" to do before and after renaming which is not possible with scripting.

Comment: You could call a .sh script via ssh in that fragment of code whatever you did or will do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your connection is getting closed because the time it takes to retrieve all the information files, you should increase the timeout connection.

You should play with the timeouts, use them wise those methods from FTPClient:

```
setDataTimeout(int timeout) //Sets the timeout in milliseconds to use when reading from the data connection.

setControlKeepAliveTimeout(long controlIdle)
//Set the time to wait between sending control connection keepalive messages when processing file upload or download.
```

Comment: I tried both timesout (date timeout => 3600 sec, ControlKeepAliveTimeout = 0,) long enough. common net FTP client behaved in the same way. Even with terminal, FTP server immediately closed connection with error code 421. (421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection). Any ideas ?